# Problem inserting data in database from option menu using ASP.NET CORE

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core

I am trying to set data in a database using dot net core, everything else inserts fine except when it is trying to pick up the data from an option menu.
Here is the code from the **view**(partially, because I don't think the whole code is necessary, if it is, please tell me I will upload it.)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance <3

```
           ` <label asp-for="Seizure">Seizure:</label>
            <select asp-for="Seizure" name="seizures" id="seizures">
                <option value="fixeddecorative">Fixed / decorative hatch</option>
                <option value="functional">Functional hatch</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="HatchTrap">Hatch trap:</label>

            <select asp-for="HatchTrap" name="hatchtraps" id="hatchtraps">
                <option value="nowindcatcher">No wind catcher</option>
                <option value="modelA">Model A</option>
                <option value="modelB">Model B</option>
                <option value="modelC">Model C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>`
```

And here is the code of my **controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("OrderId,Model,Color,Size,Seizure,HatchTrap,User")] ShutterOrders order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
        
            return View(order);
        
    }
```

The picked up values in the object:
[image: The picked up values in the object]

Comment: Can you add the error message ?

Comment: @B.S. I don't get an error message, in the debugger it doesn't get picked up at all. The object has all the other values except those from the option menu (the null value is written). And also doesn't register in the database. I will upload an image of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the `prefix`.In your code,the name of the selectlist could not match the property in `ShutterOrders` model.

And you need know that `asp-for` will generate `name` and `id` html element by default.As a sample,if you use the following code:

```
<select asp-for="HatchTrap">
</select>
```

It will generate the html in the browser:

```
<select id="HatchTrap" name="HatchTrap">
</select>
```

So,to meet your requirement,just remove the name and id(id is optional,you could remove or keep it):

```
@model ShutterOrders
<form asp-action="Create">
    //other properties...

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Seizure">Seizure:</label>
        <select asp-for="Seizure">
            <option value="fixeddecorative">Fixed / decorative hatch</option>
            <option value="functional">Functional hatch</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HatchTrap">Hatch trap:</label>

        <select asp-for="HatchTrap">
            <option value="nowindcatcher">No wind catcher</option>
            <option value="modelA">Model A</option>
            <option value="modelB">Model B</option>
            <option value="modelC">Model C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you, removing the name tag does the trick :) @Rena